# Rails 5.1 testing changed attributes Deprecation Warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I just upgraded my 5.0.1 app to 5.1 and I'm getting a *huge* amount of warnings whenever I run my rspec tests.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false= is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.2. (called from <top (required)> at /home/doomy/Documents/rsm/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:23)
...DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed_attributes` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes.transform_values(&:first)` instead. (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/doomy/Documents/rsm/spec/controllers/products_spec.rb:48)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changes` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes` instead. (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/doomy/Documents/rsm/spec/controllers/products_spec.rb:48)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes.keys` instead. (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/doomy/Documents/rsm/spec/controllers/products_spec.rb:48)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `attribute_change` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_change_to_attribute` instead. (called from block (3 levels) in <top (required)> at /home/doomy/Documents/rsm/spec/controllers/products_spec.rb:48)
```

This goes on for every test I have and ends up taking a significant while longer since it's writing so much stuff to console.

I'm rather confused as to what I should be changing as the offending code doesn't look anything out of the ordinary.

Here's products_spec.rb around line 48

```
describe "GET show" do

before(:each) do
  @product = create(:product, user: create(:product_admin))
end

context "anonymously" do
  it "renders" do
    get :show, params: { id: @product.id }
    expect(response).to render_template("show")
  end
end

context "as regular user" do
  it "renders" do
    get :show, params: { id: @product.id }
    login(create(:user))
    expect(response).to render_template("show")
  end
end
...
```

I assume it has to do something with the before filter, but I can't quite figure out what.  Searching for the warning returns nothing useful.

Thanks.

Comment: @Зелёный Yes - all the messages say something along similar lines.  My question is what am I doing wrong as I don't have any of the code mentioned in the message at the line it references and I'm unsure how to fix the problem.  Perhaps it's obvious to you but I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading Carrierwave as suggested here:
https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64/issues/53

Comment: Thanks much!  This was the issue.